# How do I ask for extended time?

Tags: leave

I have been working for my company for about 7 months. Unfortunately my husband and I live apart for now.  He is living in Croatia while we wait for his immigration to be processed.  The problem we are facing is that he has to get surgery and he will be on bed rest.  I will have to go and take care of him while he gets better. Today is the 24th, I bought my ticket for the 28th of next month. This was a sudden. development, and there is nothing else I can do. His immigration process is almost done, and he needs to get this surgery before he arrives.

Is it bad that I am giving a month in advance notice? Is that too short notice?

I know that they won't pay me, of course, but when I do come back I will still need my job, or need to find another if they cannot accommodate me.

What should I do???

Answer (score 8):

What you do is ask, explaining it just as you've explained it here. The worst that can happen is that they tell you they can't promise to hold your job for you, in which case you can start planning a job hunt so you're ready for that possibility.  And they may tell you that the job will be held for you, or even that they'll let you use sick time for part or all of this.

The only way to find out is to ask.